# flash over jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, flash, z-index

I can't get this working. I have a flash header, and a jquery slideshow on my page, but the flash goes over the jquery slideshow (the jquery slideshow appears under the flash).
Here's my page, just click on one of the left side images (those four): http://www.sleepy.ro/scutece-copii?slide=ok . Z-index does not help. Please help me out with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

To your object.

In the `<embed>` (if you have it) tag, add `wmode="transparent"`.